# how to implement long press of UIButton

Tags: iphone

I want to do a certain task if i hold and press the UIButton without release my finger, like showing some animation.so how can I execute that task when my finger is holding or pressing the UIButton?

Thanks

Comment: Good for you!  Was there a question here?

Comment: hot to implement long press of UIButton, ok ill just edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to handle touchesBegan and touchesMoved on your own view so you'll be able to time the duration its pressed.  See the [iPhone Examples website](http://www.iphoneexamples.com/) for an example.